# Unable to parse file monolog.xml, The XML file monolog.xm is not valid

Tags: xml, docker, symfony, php-8

I am using a docker image and I am running php8. I installed vendor and it's ok, the issue is when running the application, I have this error of `invalid XML file`, after all, it's installed with Symfony bundle, I tested the file with Linux command `xmllint`

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What does that file contain? Is this problem really related to Docker itself?

Comment: I fixed by going inside the container and run the command `symfony console cache:clear`
and give permission to folder /tmp inside the container.

Comment: @NicoHaase probably it's related to some compilation issue related to the OS.